# Short story where artificial life gets out of control

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, hard-sci-fi

Please bear with me, memories are vague. I'm looking for the name of a short scifi story, by a fairly prominent author IIRC, where a person was evolving "pet artificial life" in their basement. Written circa 2000, I think.

As the story proceeded the life got increasingly more complex. It started off simple but became gradually more well-defined and intelligent, resembling organisms, and later evolved a civilization. The evolution kept speeding up until one day the person came back to find his "artificial creatures" managed to break out of the confinement he imposed on them. The civilization basically became smarter than humans, and escaped ?into another dimension? via some new physics it invented, in a singularity event.

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the life was digital = evolving in a computer. But I may be wrong about that. In any case, the life was super tiny / not visible, so if not digital, maybe microscopic / nanotech or something.

Fairly short, perhaps 20 pages in total.

What I remember from the story is that the person tried to set up restrictions for what his creation could do without harming them, making the constraints ever more sophisticated as the life became smarter and smarter. But in the end, they managed to escape anyway (they vanished, basically, without harming the person or anyone else).

**EDIT**: I just went through short stories of Ted Chiang, because I thought it might have been him. But no luck there :(

Comment: This matches potentially hundreds of stories. Can you give any detail that would be unique?

Comment: @Valorum Try some biggest names first. I suspect this story is canonical, its author well-known.

Comment: Was it in a magazine? Anthology? Online?

Comment: @user124114 I don't quite understand your "I suspect this story is canonical" remark. Usually, when I see people say a particular story is "canonical," they mean "it's part of the 'official continuity' within a much larger set of stories that were all happening in the same fictional universe." Are you suggesting the story you want is one small piece of a popular series?

Comment: @Lorendiac Canonical = part of an authoritative list, an accepted "standard" element. In this case, a short story that is well known… or so I thought :(

Comment: As others have said, many such stories among them a Simpsons episode. First one might be of interest. Microcosmic God, could that be the first?

Comment: Thanks @releseabe. I checked Microcosmic God and that's not it. (also, it was published in 1940s; I'm looking for 2000±10)

Comment: The point is that there have been a *lot* of stories matching this description at a rough level. Reliably finding the one you want calls for more detail.

Comment: Yes, yes, I keep hearing there are many. Yet no suggestions. Please shoot some "big names" circa 2000±10, I can do the sorting myself. Thanks.

Comment: @user124114 - dude, I've had a couple of bad StackExchange experiences, where people gave me a hard time in the comments. The community can sometimes be pretty judgmental and uppity. But ... BUT ... you gotta give us *something* here. Help us, so we can help YOU. *Any* other details, y'know? Did the protagonist have a romantic partner? What was his day job? Was it set at the time of publication, or near future or far future? What was the color of the book's cover? Anything additional will help.

Comment: One possibility is Kathleen Ann Goonan's _[Nanotech Cycle](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?11404)_ of novels, starting with 1994's _Queen City Jazz_, set in a Cincinnati transformed by wild nanotech.

Comment: This could also be a garbled memory of "[Big Jelly](http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/AuthorSpecAlphaList.asp?BkNum=367)" by Rudy Rucker and Bruce Sterling.

Comment: Not a short story, but otherwise sounds very similar to [Permutation City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_City).

Comment: Just a guess but since "Microcosmic God" has been "taken", I'm gonna toss out "Sandkings" by George R.R. Martin who meets the definition of "fairly prominent".   It was also adapted for an episode of the "Outer Limits".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandkings_(novelette)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like ["Crystal Nights"](https://www.gregegan.net/MISC/CRYSTAL/Crystal.html) by Greg Egan, first published in 2008.

The premise is that a billionaire has bought the rights to an extraordinary powerful computer, and is using it to simulate artificial organisms in the hope that they will evolve consciousness. His initial choice to run the project turns down the job, on the grounds that natural selection requires the deaths of countless sentient simulated beings, which is incredibly immoral.

He proceeds with the project anyway, but developed his own moral qualms when the life forms develop language. At that point, he modifies the simulation to make the beings immortal, and encourages their further development using subtle cultural manipulation.

Eventually he makes contact with the civilization and gives them access to a real-world physics laboratory, which they use to escape from both their simulation and our own universe.

Comment: Eternal thanks.